# I need to update one colum if my casenddate (column) = '3000-01-01' then utlize the same date of casestartdate(column)

Tags: sql-server

I  have columns `LeaveStartDate` and `LeaveEnddate`. In some situations, `LeaveEnddate` is `3000-01-01`. So, in this case, I want to utilize the same dates which are there in `LeaveStartDate` column.

ex: if it is like this

```
LeaveStartDate     LeaveEnddate 

  2018-09-25         3000-01-01
```

I want it  to be

```
LeaveStartDate     LeaveEnddate 

  2018-09-25        2018-09-25
```

Currently I have used CTE concept to create it as a temp table. and I thought I would it later to this temp table with the above condition

Help me write a code for this or is there an example for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to update your data as your question title suggests you would just do this...

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET LeaveEnddate = LeaveStartDate
WHERE LeaveEnddate = '3000-01-01'
```

However, if you just want to select a different column based on the value of a column then you could do this...

```
SELECT LeaveStartDate,
    CASE WHEN LeaveEndDate = '3000-01-01' THEN
        LeaveStartDate
    ELSE
        LeaveEndate
    END AS LeaveEnddate
FROM YourTable
```

Do either of those help?